# error: too many arguments to function ‘strcasecmp’ "Head First C"

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the Internet Knock Knock Protocol Server from O'Reilly's Head First C working but when I try to compile it I receive the following Error.

```
ikkp_server.c:106:4: error: too many arguments to function ‘strcasecmp’
ikkp_server.c:111:6: error: too many arguments to function ‘strcasecmp’
```

those lines correspond to the lines,

```
if(strcasecmp("Who's there?", buf,12))
if(strcasecmp("Oscar who?", buf,10))
```

The full code is

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void error(char *msg){
    fprintf(stderr, "\n\t\t%s: %s\n\n", msg, strerror(errno));
    exit(errno);
}

int catch_signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)){
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    return sigaction(sig, &action, NULL);
}

int read_in(int socket, char *buf, int len){
    char *s = buf;
    int slen = len;
    int c = recv(socket, s, slen, 0);
    while ((c > 0) && (s[c-1] != '\n')){
        s += c; slen -= c;
        c = recv(socket, s, slen, 0);
    }
    if ( c < 0)
        return c;
    else if (c == 0)
        buf[0] = '\0';
    else
        s[c -1] = '\0';
    return len - slen;
}

int open_listener_socket(){
    int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s == -1)
        error("Open Socket Error");
    return s;
}

void bind_to_port(int socket, int port){
    struct sockaddr_in name;
    name.sin_family = PF_INET;
    name.sin_port = (in_port_t)htons(port);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    int reuse = 1;
    if(setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        error("Error reusing socket.");
    int c = bind( socket, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name));
    if (c == -1)
        error("Error binding socket.");

}

int say(int socket, char *s){
    int result = send(socket, s, strlen(s), 0);
    if (result == -1)
        error("Can't send message");
    return result;
}

int listener_d;

void handle_shutdown(int sig){
    if (listener_d)
        close(listener_d);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n\t\tServer Closed.\n\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(){

    //catch sig
    if(catch_signal(SIGINT, handle_shutdown) == -1)
        error("Signal Error");

    //create listener socket..
    listener_d = open_listener_socket();

    //bind listener.
    bind_to_port(listener_d, 3098);

    if(listen(listener_d, 10) == -1)
        error("Can't Listen.");

    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);

    puts("Waiting for Connection.");

    char buf[255];
    while(1){
        int connect_d = accept(listener_d, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &address_size);
        if( connect_d == -1)
            error("Client Connect Error.");

        //begin knock knock joke.
        if(say(connect_d,"Internet Knock Knock Protocol Server\r\nVersion 1.0\r\n\nKnock! Knock!\r\n"   ) != -1){
            read_in(connect_d, buf, sizeof(buf));
            if(strcasecmp("Who's there?", buf,12))
                say(connect_d,"You should say 'Who's there?'\r\n");
            else {
                if(say(connect_d,"Oscar.") != -1){
                    read_in(connect_d, buf, sizeof(buf));
                    if(strcasecmp("Oscar who?", buf,10))
                        say(connect_d, "You should say 'Oscar who?'\r\n");
                    else
                        say(connect_d, "Oscar silly question, get a silly answer!\r\n");
                }
            }
        }

        close(connect_d);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

man strcasecmp says that it should work?

int strncasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);

what am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the `n` in `strNcasecmp`. (Capitalized for emphasis, use a lower case `n` in the actual function name.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was two different function names even while looking at the man page for strcasecmp :P